# GCC warning 'comparison is always true' when comparing the return of ntohs with a integer

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I'm having a hard time to understand why I'm getting this compilation warning while using GCC 4.8.4 on Linux:

> warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]

when comparing values like these:

```
uint16_t port_number = 23620;

if (ntohs(port_number) >= 0 && ntohs(port_number) <= 1023) {
    puts("The compiler warns that I will always end up here.");
} else {
    puts("Not reached");
}
```

I understand that the problem is due to the max size supported by each value involved in this comparison. But how can I understand this better and fix it?

Comment: It's only the `>= 0` that triggers the warning, since `uint16_t` is unsigned and so always nonnegative.

Comment: Reading the man-pages of functions is always a good idea before asking.

Comment: @Olaf can you tell me where in this function's man-page there is an information that could help me? Because I haven't found anything useful there that is related with my question... Besides the uint16_t.

Comment: @HenriqueGouveia: Programming is about thinking for oneself. It is C basics: what is the smallest value an **unsigned** integer can have?

Comment: @Olaf. Sorry, couldn't find it.

Comment: _sigh_, I have my tutoring 5 minutes: When do you think `ntohs(port_number) >= 0` will ever become false?

Comment: Now I know why because of the explanation of our friends @ecatmur and charlessrstka here. Not looking at the man-page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ntohs` returns a `uint16_t`. Since `uint16_t` is unsigned, it will always be greater than or equal to `0`. Therefore, `ntohs(port_number) >= 0` will always resolve to true. This is why you're getting the warning.